# Mocking Windows Installer

Tags: testing, scripting, automation, windows-installer, vmware

Is it possible to mock the Windows Installer? I would like to set up tests for various scenarios during install. I don't really care what is stored in the Windows Installer databases, I just want to test the output of the installer packages (what files have changed, etc).

**Edit**

I suppose I could setup VMWare images and script them. Does anybody know how to script/automate tasks in VMWare instances?

Comment: You can try PowerCLi to automate VMware related tasks

Comment: do you just want to know what files are in a msi database? there are easier ways to check that! e.g. create a adminpoint (msiexec /a) or open it with orca or insted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You need two things:

1. A setup authoring tool which can generate the packages. A command line interface or scriptable solution would be great for automation.
2. A resource monitor which determines what each installation does. You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) or another tool which monitors files and registry.

As an optional feature I would also suggest a log parser. This way you can c[reate a verbose log](http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/) for each installation and analyze the log to see what it did to the target machine.

Comment: I can analyze the log, but it's hard, and not future proof. What if they change the log file format? Also, I would like to either revert the installation (complete rollback) or have the mock (my software) to just consume the actions of Windows Installer.

Comment: I doubt the log format will change, it hasn't changed much in 10 years since Windows Installer 2.0. Regarding the uninstall, it's very easy to trigger it through the msiexec command line. The installer actions cannot be consumed. They either run and do something or they don't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mock MSI.  You either trust that it works and evaluate the data in the MSI to predict what will happen or you use infrastructure automation to spin up machines and execute the installer then run tests to confirm the expected behavior.